# Creating an ER diagram for hsqldb that exports SQL

Tags: sql, database-design, hsqldb

I'm currently designing a DB scheme. I have to use hsqldb. 
- Normally I like creating an ER diagram, and I export the SQL source. Therefore I'm looking for a tool that automatically transforms my ER diagram into hsqldb sql code. Using MySQL Workbench or some sort of web interface (http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/) seems to support any server, but hsqldb.

I'm beginning to do that. Surely I can export SQL code from any tool and edit it to fit. However I think this is one step I can save... with the right diagram tool :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at SQL PowerArchitect, it supports HSQLDB:

http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect

Their homepage requires a registration in order to download it (even for the community edition), but you can download the community edition without registration from the page on google code:

http://code.google.com/p/power-architect/

Answer (score 0):

DB Visualizer can probably do that directly. The HSQLDB SQL dialect is ANSI SQL. Other SQL dialects that are close to ANSI are Firebird, DB2, Sybase, Informix and Postgres.